# Occasional 10 second delay starting an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, wear-os

I have a wearable application where WearMessageListenerService's onMessageReceived() starts an activity and everything is functioning as it should.

BUT I have observed that very occasionally there is quite a large delay, 10 seconds or so, between the call to startActivity() and the activity's onCreate() being called.

There's nothing complication going on in my code that could be causing this - its a very very simple and small program, I only have just these two classes - the listener service and the activity. There's no threads, there's no background processing, there's no synchronous calls, there's no blocking, nothing like that.

Here's some code from the WearableListenerService:

```
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "WearableListenerService onMessageReceived() with: " + messageEvent.getPath());
    Intent = ....
    ....
    Log.i(TAG, "Going to start activity");
    startActivity(intent);
```

And heres the activity's onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "***************** ACTIVITY onCreate() ******************");
    ...
```

When I observe the delay happening I can see a log such as this (abbreviated for brevity)

```
03-25 12:57:35.565   WearableListenerService onMessageReceived() with:  CALL_STATE_RINGING
03-25 12:57:35.565   Going to start activity 
03-25 12:57:43.576   WearMessageListenerService onDestroy()
03-25 12:57:45.348   *************** ACTIVITY onCreate() **************
```

Notice how there's an 8 second gap in this log before the activity gets created.

Has anybody observed delays like this with activities in general, or might this be something specific to a wearable? (in my opinion the wearable functionality seems a bit flakey, I frequently seem to observe things such as this).

Is there anything I can do to find out why there is sometimes a delay, and eliminate it.

Comment: What is the intent you pass to `startActivity`?

Comment: @Mr H. I dont see anything wrong with your code. You should try changing the launch mode of your activity to SingleInstance

Comment: @Sheraz Ahmad Khilji It already is SingleInstance

Comment: @MrH does this problem only occur incase of wearable ? Have u tried running the same type of code on Android Phone ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use wakelock before starting the activity? Your device can be put in sleep before the activity is started.
I think the best way here is to use `acqure(long timeout)` method for auto-releasing the lock.

Comment: At the same time as I am launching my activity is when there is an incoming phone call, so the device would be woken up for it to display the incoming call screen?

Answer (score -4):

It's most likely your constructor is taking a lot of time.  Check if you are initializing values on your class such as

```
class Foo {
  private int bar = someComplexObjectOp();
}
```

Some things like Paints can be put in as static values which also save in time.

Note if your class itself is very large (100 or so members) it will also take time for it to load.

Comment: If the class were large (which it isn't) or the construction was creating something lengthy (which it isn't) then surely the problem would be present all the time, whereas I said it happened very occasionally.